# How can I align entire table to right with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I align an entire table to the right with CSS?

`margin-right` does not help

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/Y2FKy/

HTML:

```
<table class="block logo">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:50%"/>
        <col style="width:50%"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>
            <table class="menu">
                <tr>
                    <td>Item 1</td>
                    <td>Item 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
table.menu {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 53):

You need to set the left margin to `auto` too. That will make the left margin push the table as far right as is allowed by the right margin.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
table, td {
    border: solid black 1px;
}
table.menu {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="block logo">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:50%"/>
        <col style="width:50%"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>
            <table class="menu">
                <tr>
                    <td>Item 1</td>
                    <td>Item 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Easy -

```css
table {
    width: 60%; /* Whichever width you want */
    margin-left: 40%; /* Minus the amount to make it 100% */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `float: right` instead:

```css
table.menu {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xM49X/)

### Solution 2:

As `float` is a not a good practice to align elements, you can use `<td style="text-align: right">` and `display: inline-table` in the table:

```html
<td style="text-align: right">
    <table border="1" class="menu">
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

```css
table.menu {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

[JSFiddle solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/gr2pL/2)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is best to avoid using `float` for alignment. It has side effects on the content that follows it.

Comment: ARgh! Don't use `align="right"`; if you want to go with that approach, use `text-align: right` in the stylesheet. And if you want an inline table, the use `display: inline-table`, not `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I have updated an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can float your table to the right by doing

```css
table {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2FKy/3/)

But **please note** that you will need to clear the float for content that comes after it

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is best to avoid using `float` for alignment. It has side effects on the content that follows it.